# Select from 2 tables to generate slug. Active Records - Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I have 2 tables. First table - offers:

`| offer_id | slug | user_id |`

and table offer_info:

`|offer_id | name | info_text |`

What I want is to create unique slug. For this first I need to create method with infinite loop, which make request and select all rows from both tables where `$name` is equal to `offers.slug` OR name is equal to `offers.slug`, but where `offer_id` is NOT equal to `$offer_id`, if there is row, loop again and check with `$name . '-' . 1`, if yes, counter is 2 and etc. If there is no result/row, break and return unique slug:

```
public function create_slug($offer_id, $name){

$count = 1;
while (true){
    // QUERIES

    if($query->num_rows()){
        $name = $name . '-' . $count; //qwerty-1
        $count++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

return $name;
}
```

, but How to make requests with Active Records ?

Comment: What are actually intending to do? Why do you need any kind of slug? You appear to be describing a SELECT query or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can user codeigniter's `url_title($str, $separator = '-', $lowercase = FALSE)` 
method. It takes a string and converts it to human readable url. For example

```
    $title = "What's wrong with CSS?";
    $url_title = url_title($title, 'underscore');
    // Produces: Whats_wrong_with_CSS
```

You can visit the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=url_title#url_title) for more info. You need to use `$this->load->helper('url');` before using the function.